# How can I use environment variable in kubernetes replication controller yaml file

Tags: yaml, kubernetes

How to read environment variables in kubernetes yaml file?
for example, I want to change the docker image tag but do not want to rewrite the file, like this

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
...
spec:
  containers:
    - name: myapp
      image: myapp:${VERSION}
 ...
```

With this I can do `kubectl rolling-update` without updating the yaml file.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you want a simple, lightweight approch you might try using [envsubst](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html). So assuming your example is in a file called `example.yaml` in a bash shell you'd execute:

```
export VERSION=69
envsubst < example.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

Also recent versions of [Kustomize](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/image.md) can do it too.

Answer (score 2):

Helm should solve your config issues - https://github.com/kubernetes/helm

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [`Deployment`](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/) coupled with `kubectl set image` like [this](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/#updating-a-deployment):

`kubectl set image deployment/nginx-deployment nginx=nginx:1.9.1`

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend using HELM. https://github.com/kubernetes/helm

You can install HELM using the information contained in the above link. That will make the `helm` command available to you.

By running `helm create YOUR_APP_NAME` it will create a directory structure like the following.

```
YOUR_APP_NAME/
  Chart.yaml          # A YAML file containing information about the chart
  LICENSE             # OPTIONAL: A plain text file containing the license for the chart
  README.md           # OPTIONAL: A human-readable README file
  values.yaml         # The default configuration values for this chart
  charts/             # OPTIONAL: A directory containing any charts upon which this chart depends.
  templates/          # OPTIONAL: A directory of templates that, when combined with values,
                      # will generate valid Kubernetes manifest files.
  templates/NOTES.txt # OPTIONAL: A plain text file containing short usage notes
```

In the `values.yaml` file you can set some ENV variables like:

```
container:
    name: "nginx"
    version: "latest"
```

In your `ReplicationController` file you can reference the variables using:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
...
spec:
  containers:
    - name: myapp
      image: {{.Values.container.name}}:{{.Values.container.version}}
...
```

The YAML file for your replication controller should be placed in the templates directory.

You can then run the command `helm package YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME`. To install the package on your K8S cluster you can then run `helm install PACKAGE_NAME`

NOTE: I would suggest you switch to using `Deployments` instead of `ReplicationController`. See: https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you mean this?

```
- name: PUBLIC_URL
  value: "http://gitserver.$(POD_NAMESPACE):$(SERVICE_PORT)"
```

This is something what their [docs](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/design/expansion.md) specified.. but it doesn't work for me anymore.